# How to Direct the Reader to the Background and Terminology Section?

Tags: thesis, writing

While writing a thesis, suppose that, one wants to inform the reader that he/she needs to have a basic knowledge of some topic to understand the following.

If the term is explained in Background and Terminology, how should I say this?

> For the readers who are not familiar with the term *blah-blah*, we
>   explain it in detail in Section 1.2.

or

> We strongly encourage our readers to read Section 1.2 to obtain
>   information about *blah-blah*.

or, what else?

Comment: There may be some conventions that come in to play. I was told it was expected that the first chapter was written at research level, and then the second has all the introductory material, more at graduate student level.

Answer (score 4):

I personally don't like making presumptions about the reader's knowledge when I am writing.  Someone may, for example, be familiar with a term or concept but use it in a difference sense than the paper does.  This is especially true in cross-disciplinary work or when there are unsettled scientific issues in play.  I thus prefer a value-neutral statement.

For example, a general pointer might be:

> See Section 2 for a review of the background and terminology of this work

while a pointer for a specific element might be:

> We thus conclude that this snark is frabjous (for more details on frabjous evaluation, see Section 2.4).